# Modifying JWT token in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, jwt, token, access-token, azure-ad-b2c

We are building an application in .NET core (not that it matters).  We are using custom policies and as apart of our user journey we are making a restful webAPI request to our API to get claims to put on the token to describe various permissions.

If I am logged in, and I modify my own permissions.  Is there a way to create a new or alter the existing token and add on my new claims WITHOUT having to re-log back in?

If so, what are they key claims that I need to re-create?

If possible, bonus points if you can point me to C# solution/example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you modify the token it becomes invalid (because of the signature). Only the issuer (API/auth server) can issue a new token.

Comment: As above, highly unadvised to do this since it means you must trust yourself to do token issuance and token validation. At that point why use a cloud solution at all?